# Class constructor that requires all parameters and all parameters be named

Tags: c#, initialization

Is there a way to define my class so that callers of that class would get a compile time error unless they specified every property of the class, with the additional constraint that the parameters pass be named?

Let's say I have this interface:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string FirstName {get;}
    string MiddleName { get; }
    string LastName { get;}
}
```

And these classes:

```
public class PersonNeedAllProperties : IPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set;} // ideally readonly
    public string MiddleName { get; private set;}
    public string LastName { get; private set;}

    public PersonNeedAllProperties(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string middleName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.MiddleName = middleName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class PersonCanNamePropertiesButNotSadlyNotRequired : IPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;} // ideally readonly
    public string MiddleName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

Then the problems with these imho are the following:

```
var p1 = new PersonNeedAllProperties("lastName", "firstName", "middle");
 // woops wrong order because not named.

var p2 = new PersonCanNamePropertiesButNotSadlyNotRequired()
{
    FirstName = "firstName",
    LastName = "lastName"
}; // woops forgot all about the middlename.
```

Is there not a way to get a simple POCO object with an initalization similar to person two but that requires that *all* the properties be named?

Here is the fiddle of the above: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUk8eT#

Comment: You cannot have the compiler force a consumer of your class to name parameters when specifying a constructor. Wh would you want to do that?

Comment: @EricJ: The goal is to avoid scenarios like scenario 1.  Sometimes we have multiple strings and it's fairly simple to confuse the order.  My goal is to have there be as little possibility for a fellow dev to create a bug as possible.

Comment: So make all devs  spell out the names.  Good idea as they like extra keystrokes.

Comment: @Paparazzi: lol that's a good point but I don't see a good middleground.

Comment: If you cannot trust a developer to a proper ctor then there is no middle ground.

Comment: @Paparazzi: That might be true, but it happens to everyone now and again.  Intellisense helps whilst typing, but when it comes to code review or debugging, this kind of thing is incredibly difficult to notice.

Comment: Keystroke them into compliance.  Good long term play.  And just how does that guarantee the proper value?  What about method call?   You going to force them to be named input also?

Comment: @Paparazzi: Lol that's not the answer I'm looking for either.  I honestly don't know what to do.  Ideally we only have to name the ones that could get confusing.  I'm not sure.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you cannot trust developer to a ctor then just don't do the project.  Really!

Comment: @Paparazzi: Maybe.  Don't worry I'm not pushing any practices on any of my teammates just looking for a solution we can all agree on.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question No, this is not possible.

You ask to be able to force two things:

- a) force all properties be set
- b) force properties to be named.

These things can be done on their own but they cannot be combined because the methods for doing so are diametrically opposed as described below.

a) To force all properties be set you need to take them as inputs in a constructor.

b) To force properties to be set by name they cannot be specified in the constructor.

Side note: It is possible to provide named parameters to a constructor but it is not possible to force these i.e `var person = new Person(firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', middleName: 'A')`

The closest you can get is to mark your properties readonly (private set) and have them only be set from within your constructor as you have done in your `PersonNeedAllProperties` class.

Something that might be a viable alternative is called the [Builder Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern).
This will have an extra class that is responsible for constructing your object, but you still wouldn't be able to get a compile time error, only runtime.

Comment: +1 for being probably correct.  That's unfortunate however.  Any way to prove that it's not possible?  Thanks.

Comment: @user420667 I've added some extra info that should help you get closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There's a horrible horrible way to *almost* enforce this.  Not by *name* but by *type*.  i'm not recommending it.  but there is a horrible way to do it.  did i mention it is horrible?

> "any problem in computer science can be solved by adding another layer of indirection" - Wheeler?

Make each of the properties their own *distinct type*.  now you can't pass them in the wrong order or the compiler will tell you that you passed an invalid type.

```
public class FirstName
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MiddleName
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}

public class LastName
{
    string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson
{
    FirstName FirstName {get;}
    MiddleName MiddleName { get; }
    LastName LastName { get;}
}

public class PersonNeedAllProperties : IPerson
{
    public FirstName FirstName { get; private set;} // ideally readonly
    public MiddleName MiddleName { get; private set;}
    public LastName LastName { get; private set;}

    public PersonNeedAllProperties(
        FirstName firstName,
        MiddleName lastName,
        LastName middleName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.MiddleName = middleName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't get you everything you want, but it does force people to pass specific params in order.  you might omit the interface entirely and only have a concrete class if you want to enforce them to be non-null though.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea for some of our scenarios.  A lot of times it's not the naming it's strings that should be interpreted (and validated) as other things e.g. URIs or EnglishNames.  Other times though it's just plain booleans and seeing a string of True/Falses isn't fun to review / debug.  One proposal aroudn the bool problem was Enums.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with a nested class I guess:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string MiddleName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }

    //Make sure the parameterless constructor is private
    private Person() { }

    private Person(string first, string middle, string last)
    {
        this.FirstName = first;
        this.MiddleName = middle;
        this.LastName = last;
    }

    public class Builder
    {
        private Person person = new Person();

        public Builder WithFirstName(string first)
        {
            person.FirstName = first;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder WithMiddleName(string middle)
        {
            person.MiddleName = middle;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder WithLastName(string last)
        {
            person.LastName = last;
            return this;
        }

        public IPerson Build()
        {
            if (person.FirstName != null
                && person.MiddleName != null
                && person.LastName != null)

                return person;

            throw new Exception("Cannot build person because reasons...");
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var person = new Person.Builder()
                    .WithFirstName("Rob")
                    .WithMiddleName("<I have no middle name>")
                    .WithLastName("Janssen")
                    .Build();
```

You can use the `With...` methods in any order you like:

```
var person = new Person.Builder()
                    .WithLastName("Janssen")
                    .WithFirstName("Rob")
                    .WithMiddleName("<I have no middle name>")
                    .Build();
```

[Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWk6xC)

---

Edit: Crap; I din't notice the other requirement of *compile time* errors.

This does, however, 'force' you to set all 3 required fields and 'forces' you to "name" the field using the `With...` methods which makes it hard to confuse the values and also allows you to specify the values in the order you desire. It also prevents you from instantiating a `Person` yourself and also allows you to have your private setters (e.g. 'read only' properties) and keeps your interface intact. The *only* thing missing here is *compile time* errors; you won't get one here. Maybe [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) can help in that department, but that would *at least* require some 'team coordination' (e.g. everyone needs to [install an extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1ec7db13-3363-46c9-851f-1ce455f66970) and have [static checking enabled](http://offbyoneprogrammer.com/blog/index.php/2015/09/07/code-contracts-in-visual-studio-2015/)); and I'm not 100% sure if it can be done with code contracts either.

Comment: Interesting near-solution to the OP's issue.

Comment: While not exactly what I had in mind, thank you for providing both an example of the builder pattern as well as something so fluent.  Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No, interfaces aren't designed to behave that way.

An interface assure you that the classes who implements it will have all the elements declared in the interface. But doesn't make any statements on how they are going to be implemented.

You can accomplish what you want with an abstract class with a custom constructor.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public abstract string FirstName {get; protected set; }
    public abstract string MiddleName { get; protected set; }
    public abstract string LastName { get; protected set; }

    public Person(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName){
        FirstName = firstName;
        MiddleName = middleName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class PersonNeedAllProperties : Person
{
    public override string FirstName{get; protected set;}
    public override string MiddleName{get; protected set;}
    public override string LastName{get; protected set;}

    public PersonNeedAllProperties(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string middleName)
        : base(firstName, lastName, middleName)
    {
    }
}
```

The custom constructor force you to complete the names in the child classes.

You can combine this answer with the one of [John Gardner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804805/6242744) using classes instead of strings for the names (firstName, middleName, lastName) to simulate the named parameters.

You need to be aware of the limitations of this method, in C# you cannot inherit from more than one class, so you need to keep this restriction in mind if you decide to implement this solution.